# How to build OkHttp3 jar file from source code

Tags: okhttp

I want to build a jar file from [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) library source code to use a **snapshot** version in my android app. I can not figure out how.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git clone https://github.com/square/okhttp
cd okhttp
./gradlew jar
mkdir /tmp/okhttplibs
find . -name '*.jar' | xargs -I % cp % /tmp/okhttplibs
```